# htaccess rewrite rules do not work in child directories.

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following htaccess code for rewrite my url site.com/page.php?id=1 to site.com/page/1.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If I add 8 rewrite rules to the main htaccess file, it may increase execution time. So I'm planning to create  directories like page and place a new htaccess files into each one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But this code doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

That rule will loop. You need to add some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But having 8 rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

doesn't really increase execution time that significantly (unless you are on a really slow server).

Comment: i am using VPS ,then i can continue with 8 rules i am already following is it ?

Comment: @RahulR It's a trade-off. Do you want 1 htaccess files with 8 rules? Or do you have 8 htaccess files in 8 different directories with 1 rule? For sure, it's going to be marginally faster to have 8 htaccess files with 1 rule, but you are probably never going to be able to tell the difference.